# What are some book suggestions for further reading about Camus and the absurd, after reading the Stranger and Myth of Sisyphus?

Tags: reference-request, existentialism, camus

I read *The Stranger* a long time ago, but I'm sure I missed a lot. More recently I've read a bit of Kierkegaard and now I'm making my way through *The Myth of Sisyphus* (and am more inclined to agree with Camus than Kierkegaard). I'm hoping to find a book giving commentary or going into more detail about Camus and his existential views.

I see *The Cambridge Companion to Camus* but I was wondering if there were any other (or better?) suggestions.

I don't really have a formal philosophy background; mostly just familiar with Foucalt and whatever's been covered by *The Partially Examined Life*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**"Albert Camus: From the Absurd to Revolt" by John Foley**
[http://www.amazon.com/Albert-Camus-Absurd-John-Foley/dp/0773534679](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0773534679)

**"Rethinking the Politics of Absurdity: Albert Camus, Postmodernity, and the Survival of Innocence" by Matthew H. Bowker**
 -- ISBN: 978-0415717618, preview available on Amazon

**"Albert Camus and the Philosophy of the Absurd" by Avi Sagi**
 -- ISBN: 9789042012301, preview available on Google Books

I can't attest to how well these will fit your needs, but there are many sites that allow you to preview books before buying them, so you can check them out first.

There are also quite a few *fiction* books on the topic of Absurdism:
http://alangullette.com/lit/absurd/

Note: I would've posted the links to all the previews, but I don't have a high enough reputation to do that. I hope what I provided is helpful.